Crazy Basement Rough in and Placement - Need help with Layout
TLDR: Strange rough-in. Need layout for full bath, less than 55' if possible. Ignore tape lines.
Need help deciphering this rough in layout. It seems a bit counter-intuitive to us and we're having trouble deciding how to place the fixtures in a way that meets code and is functional. I even checked the builder's floor plans for optional finished basements (we didn't work with the builder, but we know who built the house when it was new) and they all had standard vanity, toilet, shower layouts against an outer wall. This is in the middle of the room and in a way that prevents everything from lining up nicely (unless I'm missing something.)
As a side note, it is helpful if the room is able to stay under 55 sqft, as then we won't have to add in another sprinkler. I've attached a taped off version of one of our plans, which includes a privacy wall and door for a standing shower, but that would require a plumber to come an add another sprinkler. I also included the floor plan for the basement remodel and a scaled up version that shows where the pipes are.
Note: The bathroom is going in the area labeled "Playroom: Finished Space" because we decided to add in a bathroom after submitting the first plan.




Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It's not clear if keeping the existing sprinklers is a hard and fast requirement.

@KMJ It isn't a hard and fast requirement, but we would prefer to as we wouldn't need to hire someone to move them.

Are you doing all the rest of the plumbing yourself? If you are hiring any of that out, adding the sprinkler change to the call should be trivial.
